# Angular 8: How to get selected data from Dynamic radio button

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7, angular8

How to get data from Dynamic radio button(radio button is generate from json data). The radio button is successfully display but how i can get the selected data from dynamic radio button.

Example Json Data:

```
[{Key : color,Values : [{Value : red}]}]
```

product.component.ts

```html
   <div class="form-group product__option" *ngFor="let item of product.productAttr; let i = index">
                    <label class="product__option-label">{{item.key}}</label>
                    <div class="input-radio-label">
                        <div class="input-radio-label__list">
                            <label *ngFor="let value of item.values; let i = index">
                                <input type="radio" id="{{value.key}}" value="{{value.value}}" name="{{item.key}}" (change)="onItemChange($event)">
                                <span>{{value.value}}</span>
                            </label>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: is it possible to create in stackblitz.com

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l5jvcd had added on stackblitz.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `onItemChange` method in your **product.component.ts** file.

```
onItemChange(value){
   console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the onItemChange method in your component.ts file.

`onItemChange(itemKey, itemValue) {
    console.log(itemKey + ' ' + itemValue);
  }`

ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipm7s6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ok got it, but how to save the selected item on array for example key is color and selected value is red. When i change the selected value to blue the color in array will change to blue

Comment: just declare new variable selectedValue as array, and assign the data you got from  @Arunkumar's function to that array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (change) event on dynamically created radio button and then you can pass values to it and then use it on ts file.

eg.

HTML

```
 <input class="option" type="radio" value="{{optionsVal.id}}" 
                      id="opt_{{optionsVal.id}}" name="quizOption"
                      (change)="radioFun( optionsVal.id)"
                       />
```

TS

```
 radioFun(optionID: any) {
console.log(optionID)
}
```

So that you can also save and push values to any particular array as you wish on radioFun function.